# HTTP served page marked as insecure in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security

As of January Chrome will show it's users that a site is being insecure if it contains either a password or credit-card field and isn't served via https. (see https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html )

This circumstance raises a little problem: 
When you have a web service running locally (for example the web-login page of your router at home ) which is not served with HTTPS since there is the strong possibility that the certificate will expire before the user updates it's software, your user will see this warning.

Mocking the password-field seems too hacky and will likely cause problems on mobile devices.

What would be good alternatives to solve this problem without serving the site with HTTPS?

Comment: no workarounds available, this is the wanted result: Move the web over https.

Answer (score 1):

You should not consider this a problem, but a feature.

If you're running the service on HTTP instead of HTTPS, then your users should expect to be warned about it. Allowing for any exceptions to Chrome`s new rule would be likely to cause uncertainty.

The fact that a site owner is worried a certificate will expire is no excuse: Would it not be preferable to use certificates anyway, and rather risk getting a warning about an *outdated* certificate instead? That is at least a *visible* problem that can be fixed fairly easily.

If the new standard implies that a user should be warned about an insecure connection, then hiding that warning means the standard is broken, and that you're providing an false sense of security, which may be worse than no security.

If you want to host a page over an unencrypted connection, that's up to you, but you should probably just accept that the warning will be shown.